# Perl -- uninitialized variable

Tags: perl, file, variables, initialization

What is going on? I've created a simple program to read the lines and prints on a file the output. But it throws some errors...

Here's the code and the explanation of it is on the comments:

```
use warnings;
use List::MoreUtils qw(indexes);

my @array_words = ();
my @array_split = ();
my @array_of_zeros = (0);
my $index = 0;

open my $info, 'models/busquedas.csv';
open my $model, '>>models/model.txt';

#First while is to count the words and store it into an array
while( my $line = <$info>)  {
    @array_split = regex($line);
    for (my $i=0; $i < scalar(@array_split); $i++) {
            # Get the index if the word is repeated
        $index = indexes { $_ eq $array_split[$i] } $array_words[$i];
            # if the word is not repeated then save it to the array by 
            # checking the index
        if ($index != -1){ push(@array_words, $array_split[$i]); }
    }
}

print $model @array_words;

sub regex{
    # get only basic info like: 'texto judicial madrid' instead of the full url
    if ($_[0] =~ m/textolibre=/ and 
        $. < 3521239 && 
        $_[0] =~ m/textolibre=(.*?)&translated/) {
        return split(/\+/, $_[0]);
    }
}
```

And the errors that I don't understand are:

```
Use of uninitialized value $index in numeric ne (!=) at classifier.pl line 21, <$info> line 12216.
Use of uninitialized value $index in numeric ne (!=) at classifier.pl line 21, <$info> line 12216.
Use of uninitialized value $index in numeric ne (!=) at classifier.pl line 21, <$info> line 12216.
Use of uninitialized value $index in numeric ne (!=) at classifier.pl line 21, <$info> line 12217.
Use of uninitialized value $index in numeric ne (!=) at classifier.pl line 21, <$info> line 12217.
Use of uninitialized value $index in numeric ne (!=) at classifier.pl line 21, <$info> line 12217.
Use of uninitialized value $index in numeric ne (!=) at classifier.pl line 21, <$info> line 12217.
Use of uninitialized value $index in numeric ne (!=) at classifier.pl line 21, <$info> line 12217.
Use of uninitialized value $index in numeric ne (!=) at classifier.pl line 21, <$info> line 12218.
Use of uninitialized value $index in numeric ne (!=) at classifier.pl line 21, <$info> line 12218.
```

Why uninitialized `$index` ? I have declared it and initialized it with a 0 value!
How can I fix this?

Comment: I think you have misunderstood how the `indexes` function works.. It is supposed to have a list to iterate over, not a single element. It returns indexes, and you already have the index for that item: `$i`.

Comment: Why do you call `indexes` on a single element of `@array_words` and not the whole array?

Comment: But how can I do to have like .indexof() function on other languages? @nwellnhof

Comment: I think you want to use `$index = first_index { $_ eq $array_split[$i] } @array_words;`. BTW, using a hash to check for duplicates should be a lot faster if you're working with larger datasets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have initialized the variable with zero, but then you change its value with

```
$index = indexes { $_ eq $array_split[$i] } $array_words[$i];
```

The function probably returns an undef (because `$array_words[$i]` does not eq `$array_split[$i]`). It would return one otherwise, as there is only one element in the list.

BTW, initializing a variable outside of a loop is a bad practice if you do not need its value outside the loop. You can declare `my $index` at the same line where you populate it with `indexes`.

Comment: `indexes` returns the list indices for which the block evaluates to true. If it is (incorrectly) used in scalar context like this, the result will be the *last* such index, or `undef` if no element of the list satisfies the criterion. It will *never* *"return one"* unless the *second* element of the list is the last one to pass the test.

Comment: @Borodin: Oh really? `perl -MList::MoreUtils=indexes -E '$x = indexes {$_ lt "c"} qw/c b d e a/;say $x'` returns `2`, but the indexes returned are 1 and 4.

Comment: That gives me `4` on my system. Is your `List::MoreUtils` up to date? Run `perl -MList::MoreUtils -E 'say $List::MoreUtils::VERSION'` the latest version is 0.33.

Comment: @Borodin: The version was 0.30. After the upgrade, I am getting 4. But the documentation states "This is just like grep", but `grep` returns the number of matches in scalar context.

Comment: Yes, I read that too. Seems like a retrograde step, but nevertheless that's what it does. It's the difference between returing a *list* and an *array*. `grep` does the latter.

Answer (score 0):

As has been observed, the `indexes` subroutine does't work like that. It returns a *list* of indices for which the block evaluates to *true*. It is wrong to use it in scalar context like this.

If you were to use a library for this, you would want `any` - also from [`List::MoreUtils`](https://metacpan.org/module/List%3a%3aMoreUtils). The code would look like this

```
while( my $line = <$info>)  {
    @array_split = regex($line);
    for my $word (@array_split) {
      push @array_words, $word unless any { $_ eq $word } @array_words;
    }
}
```

However I think you want something much simpler. From my understanding of your code a Perl hash will do what you need.

I have refactored your program like this. I hope it helps.

Essentially, each "word" in the line is pushed onto `@array_words` if it isn't already in the hash.

You also appear to have a bug in your `regex` subroutine. The statement

```
return split(/\+/, $_[0]);
```

splits the *whole line* and returns the result. I think it should split just the query part of the URL that you have just extracted, like this

```
return split /\+/, $1;
```

Ordinarily you should check to see that `open` calls succeeded. Adding the `autodie` pragma does this implicitly for you.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

open my $info,  '<',  'models/busquedas.csv';
open my $model, '>>', 'models/model.txt';

my %unique_words;
my @array_words;

#First while is to count the words and store it into an array
while( my $line = <$info>)  {
  for my $word (regex($line)) {
    push @array_words, $word unless $unique_words{$word}++;
  }
}

print $model "$_\n" for @array_words;

sub regex {

  my ($line) = @_;

  # get only basic info like: 'texto judicial madrid' instead of the full url
  return unless $line =~ /textolibre=/ and $. < 3521239;
  if ( $line =~ /textolibre=(.*?)&translated/ ) {
    return split /\+/, $1;
  }
}
```